# How to sort by KIND in helm-find-files (Emacs)

Tags: helm

I know there is such a variable as helm-ff-initial-sort-method.
However, it does not include KIND as a sorting method.
Anybody know how to sort files in helm-find-file by KIND?
Thank you!

Comment: Not sure how to get a file's KIND, by extension? is it good enough? I notice macOS's Finder can distinguish plain text and unix executable even both of them do not have extension. helm-find-files's sorting is done via helm-list-directory.

Comment: Yes, KIND is the extension. I did not understand your point regarding helm-list-directory. My goal is to just sort the files using helm-find-file by kind (or extension). Basically, having all folders on top and everything else below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to add <kbd>Shift-F4</kbd> to sort by kind:

```
(define-advice helm-list-directory (:override (directory) add-sort-by-kind)
  (let ((files (directory-files directory t directory-files-no-dot-files-regexp)))
    (pcase helm-ff-initial-sort-method
      ('nil
       files)
      ('newest
       (sort files #'file-newer-than-file-p))
      ('size
       (sort files #'helm-ff-file-larger-that-file-p))
      ('kind
       (let-alist (seq-group-by #'file-directory-p files)
         (nconc
          .t                            ; folders
          (sort
           .nil                         ; files
           (lambda (f1 f2)
             (let ((ext1 (or (file-name-extension f1) ""))
                   (ext2 (or (file-name-extension f2) "")))
               (if (equal ext1 ext2)
                   (string< f1 f2)
                 (string< ext1 ext2)))))))))))

(defun helm-ff-sort-by-kind ()
  (interactive)
  (unless (eq helm-ff-initial-sort-method 'kind)
    (setq helm-ff-initial-sort-method 'kind)
    (helm-force-update (helm-get-selection nil helm-ff-transformer-show-only-basename)))
  (message "Sorting by kind"))
(put 'helm-ff-sort-by-kind 'helm-only t)

(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "S-<f4>") #'helm-ff-sort-by-kind)
```

Change `helm-ff-initial-sort-method` does not work for me, e.g., `(setq helm-ff-initial-sort-method 'size)`, that is, the initial sort is still by alpha instead of by size, I am not sure if I understand the user option correctly. However, <kbd>Shift-F1/F2/F3</kbd> work.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is "add-sort-by-kind" a variable that I should already have in my system? I can't find it.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein Nope, it's not a variable name, it's the NAME argument of define-advice, type `C-h f define-advice` to see its meaning.

Comment: Thanks, newbie with elisp. I added the function to my init. Evaluated it as I have done with others, but I can't find M-x helm-ff-sort-by-kind. Any ideas?

Comment: The command does not make sense outside a helm-find-files session. You need to use the keybinding Shift-F4 while helm-find-files is running. The reason why the command does not appear in helm-M-x (I assume your M-x is helm-M-x) is probably filtered by helm-M-x. Since you're new to Emacs Lisp, the above code might be difficult to understand, I suggest don't put it to your init file. You can consider the feature you want is not supported by helm-find-files. Maybe try dired with GNU ls's -X option: `-X     sort alphabetically by entry extension`.

Comment: Learning a lot, thanks! Will try this. One question though: I did not get how ot use dired with GNU ls -X option. What exactly shall I type on my emacs? Thanks.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein Launch Dired via `M-x dired` and add the `-X` flag via `C-u s -lX`. Assuming you have GNU Coreutils's ls, BSD's does not have the flag. Besides, in your terminal, you can enter `ls -lX` to try the feature. And note it does not do exactly what you want, that is, it does not sort folders in the beginning.

Comment: I do M-x dired and ENTER. Then when I type C-u s... it breaks the flow, because it types an "s" to find all files containing an "s".

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein The s keybinding runs the dired-sort-toggle-or-edit command in dired, not C-s which runs I-search.

Comment: I honestly don't know how to type this sequence. Maybe you could tell me exactly the one-by-one character I must type? As I said, I do M-x dired, followed by ENTER. Then I do C-u s, and this 's' breaks the flow.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein In vanilla Emacs, e.g., Emacs -Q, in Dired, "s runs the command dired-sort-toggle-or-edit (found in dired-mode-map),", in other words, you can also use M-x dired-sort-toggle-or-edit, the C-u is the prefix argument applied to dired-sort-toggle-or-edit. The dired uses the ls command to list files of a directory, and the ls command provides command line flags to sort files by name, size, extension etc, what you're going to do is add the -X flag so ls sorts files by extensions.

Comment: .Ok, it works for some reason now. Thanks.